# How to pass cell templates to a component with b-table?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue, vuejs-slots

I created a component that shows table data for various pages. That component uses **b-table** inside. Now for a couple pages I want to customize rendering of some columns, and Bootstrap Tables allow that using scoped field slots with special syntax:

```
    <template #cell(field)="data">
            {{ data.item.value }}
    </template>
```

where field - column name, coming from my array with columns, and data.item - cell item to be rendered.

The problem is that I have different fields for different pages, so this customization should come from parent component, and these templates should be created dynamically.

Here is how I tried to solve it:

Pass via property to MyTableComponent an array with customizable fields and unique slot names
In MyTableComponent dynamically create templates for customization, and inside dynamically create named slots

From parent pass slot data to named slots

**MyTableComponent:**

```
    <b-table>
        <template v-for="slot in myslots" v-bind="cellAttributes(slot)">
            <slot :name="slot.name"></slot>
        </template>
    </b-table>

    <script>
        ...
        computed: {
            cellAttributes(slot) {
                return ['#cell(' + slot.field + ')="data"'];
            }
        }
        ...
    </script>
```

**Parent:**

```
    <MyTableComponent :myslots="myslots" :items="items" :fields="fields">
        <template slot="customSlot1">
                Hello1
        </template>
        <template slot="customSlot1">
                Hello2
        </template>
    </MyTableComponent>

<script>
    ...
    items: [...my items...],
    fields: [...my columns...],
    myslots: [
        { field: "field1", name: "customSlot1" },
        { field: "field2", name: "customSlot2" }
    ]
    ...
</script>
```

Unfortunately, **b-table** component just ignores my custom slots like if they are not provided. It works if I specify in the MyTableComponent it directly:

```
    <b-table>
          <template #cell(field1)="data">
            {{ data.item.value }}
          </template>
    </b-table>
```

But I need it to be done dynamically via component properties. Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Dynamic Slot Names](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Dynamic-Slot-Names) feature of Vue 2 to pass all (or some) slots from parent to `<b-table>` inside child like this:

Child:

```html
<b-table>
  <template v-for="(_, slotName) of $scopedSlots" v-slot:[slotName]="scope">
    <slot :name="slotName" v-bind="scope"/>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

[$scopedSlots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-scopedSlots) contains all slots passed to your component.

Now this will work:

```html
    <MyTableComponent :items="items" :fields="fields">
          <template #cell(field1)="data">
            {{ data.item.value }}
          </template>
    </ MyTableComponent>
```

**UPDATE 2 - Vue 3**

To make above code work in Vue 3, just replace `$scopedSlots` with `$slots` as suggested by [migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/slots-unification.html)

**UPDATE 1**

> You can filter `$scopedSlots` if you want (have some slot specific to your wrapper component you don't want to pass down to `<b-table>`) by creating `computed`

I mentioned this possibility in my original answer but it is a bit problematic so it deserves better explanation...

1. Scoped slots are passed to a component as a functions (generating VNode's when called). Target component just executes those she knows about (by name) and ignores the rest. So lets say your wrapper has `b-table` (or `v-data-table` for Vuetify) inside and some other component, let's say pagination. You can use code above inside both of them, passing all slots to each. Unless there is some naming conflict (both components using same slot name), it will work just fine and does not induce any additional cost (all slot functions are already compiled/created when passed to your wrapper component). Target component will use (execute) only the slots it knows by name.
2. **If there is possible** naming conflict, it can be solved by using some naming convention like prefixing slot names intended just for `b-table` with something like `table--` and doing filtering inside but be aware that `$scopedSlots` object **does contain some Vue internal properties which must be copied along !!** (`$stable`, `$key` and `$hasNormal` for Vue 2 - see the [code](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/b51430f598b354ed60851bb62885539bd25de3d8/src/core/vdom/helpers/normalize-scoped-slots.js)). So the filtering code below even it's perfectly fine and doesn't throw any error **will not work** (`b-table` will not recognize and use the slots)

```html
<b-table>
  <template v-for="(_, slotName) of tableSlots" v-slot:[slotName]="scope">
    <slot :name="slotName" v-bind="scope"/>
  </template>
</b-table>
```

```js
computed: {
    tableSlots() {
      const prefix = "table--";
      const raw = this.$scopedSlots;
      const filtered = Object.keys(raw)
        .filter((key) => key.startsWith(prefix))
        .reduce(
          (obj, key) => ({
            ...obj,
            [key.replace(prefix, "")]: raw[key],
          }),
          {}
        );
      return filtered;
    },
  },
```

This code can be fixed by including the properties mentioned above but this just too much dependency on Vue internal implementation for my taste and I do not recommend it. If it's possible, stick with the scenario 1...

Comment: Wow, Michael, it's really a cool feature, now I can configure my b-table with data in one component, reuse it in most of my pages, but still I can adjust in almost any way I need from a parent. It works, thank you so much!

Comment: It indeed is! Had same "wow" moment when I discovered something like this is possible :)

Comment: @MichalLevý How would you filter these $scopedSlots? I'm looking for a way to do the v-for loop only for slots starting with `table--`. I'm wondering what logic to provide in the computed property.

Comment: @caca_pj It's not really needed. Scoped slots are passed to a component as a functions (generating VNode's). Target component just executes those she knows and ignores the rest...

Comment: @MichalLevý Consider you want to render specific slots at different places. Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-bose-yi8x0

Comment: @studio-pj You can render the slot content how many time you wish (it is just a function that gets executed)