# How to render a custom component in <b-table> Bootstrap Vue? (Vue.js 2)

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

How can I show a custom component- BaseButton.vue in the rows of the table, if table component and button are common components?

I made the component BaseTable.vue. I use this component for all tables.

```
<template>
  <b-table :fields="fields" :items="items"></b-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
      props: {
        fields:{
          type: Array,
          require: true
        },
        items:{
          type: Array,
          require: true
        },
}
```

fields - object in a parent component.
items - object from API.

Parent component (base button doesn't appear in table on page):

```
<template>
  <base-table :fields="fields" :items="items">
    <template #cell(actions)>
      <base-button></base-button>
    </template>
  <base-table>
</template>

<script>
  import BaseButton from '...';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fields: [
        { key: 'Caption', label: 'Name' },
        { key: 'PreviousMonthCounter', label: 'Prev. month' },
        { key: 'CurrentMonthCounter', label: 'Curr. month' },
        { key: 'actions', label: 'Action' }
      ],
      items: []
    }
  },

  components: {
    BaseButton
  }
}
```

And now I need to render BaseButton.vue in the last column of the table and I can't to make it - table has only text fields from items.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass cell templates to a component with b-table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64636803/how-to-pass-cell-templates-to-a-component-with-b-table)

Comment: yes, like that, but i think my variant is better. From bootstrap community i found out :)

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Question is clear duplicate. Also other question is much better formulated. Answer is badly formatted, the code is longer, contains no further explanation and uses `slot` and `slot-scope` which is [deprecated](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#slot-deprecated)

Comment: Hm... may be you are right... need to look better, because my code is working  but.... dont want to rewrite code but i could to write better )

Answer (score 0):

Need to create a child component (BaseTable):

```
<template>
<b-table :items="items" :fields="fields">
  <slot v-for="slot in Object.keys($slots)" :name="slot" :slot="slot" />
  <template v-for="slot in Object.keys($scopedSlots)" :slot="slot" slot-scope="scope">
    <slot :name="slot" v-bind="scope"></slot>
  </template>
</b-table>
</template>
```

And use it in the parent component like , but  must be replaced by your component name.

For example:

```
<base-table :fields="fields" :items="items">
<template #cell(nameOfTheField)="{item}">
  {{ item.key }}
</template>
<template #cell(nameOfTheField)>
  <base-button></base-button>
</template>
```